# Dynamically render information from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, html-table

I have this data:

```
"PensionPlanSummary": [
        {
            "Type": "DefinedContributionPension",
            "Participants": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 425.0
                }
            ],
            "TotalAssets": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 629282.0
                }
            ],
            "NetAssets": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 629282.0
                }
            ],

        },
        {
            "Type": "Welfare",
            "Participants": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 252.0
                },
                {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "Value": 389.0
                }
            ],
            "TotalAssets": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "Value": 0.0
                }
            ],
            "NetAssets": [
                {
                    "Year": 2018,
                    "Value": 0.0
                },
                {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "Value": 0.0
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
```

I want to render data in this table:
[image]

Focus only on Participants. As you can see the data is not populated correct because it is populating by row and for example it should skip 2016 and 2017 for DefinedContributionPension and to fill 2018.
This table is result of this code:

```
{element.Participants.reverse().map((el, ind) => {
                              return uniqueYears.map((e, i) => {
                                // console.log(el.Year);
                                if (el.Year == e) {
                                  console.log(el.Year);
                                  return (
                                    <td key={ind}>
                                      ${numeral(el.Value).format("0,0")}
                                    </td>
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return <td key={ind}> - </td>;
                                }
                              });
                            })}
```

uniqueYears =[2016,2017,2018]
element is the single object (I have another map above). So as you can see I am mapping 1 time the participants and 1 time unique years and finding the 1 record that is true for the condition of equality of the element year. As you can see it is not putting the dash - and it is not populating table correct. I tried looping in other way - first to loop over the uniqueYears array and then to element.Participants but again it not worked as expected. Any ideas how to make it?
P.S.: Table should look like this way:
[image]

But lets focus only on participants as in example.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried coming up with a very dirty solution in as little as time as possible, but it seems to be working for me

`pensionPlans` and `uniqueYears` are arrays that you have mentioned. My code is below

```
pensionPlans.map(e => {
    if(e.Type === "DefinedContributionPension"){
uniqueYears.map(year => {
    e.Participants.map(item => {
    if(item.Year === year){
     console.log('found')
    } else {
    console.log("not found")
    }
    })
})
  }
})
```

Also, I notice that you have used `==` instead of `===` while checking for `if (el.Year == e)`. Although correct, this might have some implications later as it doesn't check the type.

You can see my answer running in console here https://jsfiddle.net/z65mp0s8/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I made a solution for your problem!

So, to get the years from your table, I made a simple function, which just returns the years from your `statistics table header`, instead of using the pre-defined `uniqueYears = [2016, 2017, 2018]`, but feel free to use it if you need.

> Obs.: The advantage of using this function is that you don't need to update your year heading and you uniqueYears array, update only your html table headings and you get the new data for all.

```
function getYears() {
  let years = [];
  for(const cell of document.querySelectorAll("[data-statistics='year'] th")) {
    if(cell.innerText.trim() !== "") years.push(parseInt(cell.innerText));
  }
  return years;
}
```

So if you choose to use the function above make sure you have in yout html table this, the `data-statistics="year"` is required by the function.

```html
<thead>
    <tr data-statistics="year">
        <th></th>
        <th>2016</th>
        <th>2017</th>
        <th>2018</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Right after, to get the entries of each one of your data, you can use the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which gives you the `key` and the `entry` of each property of your object.
The [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is to remove the `type` property, focusing only on the statistics data.

```js
for(const Plan of PensionPlanSummary) {
  let PlanEntries = Object.entries(Plan);

  PlanEntries = PlanEntries.splice(1, PlanEntries.length - 1);
  for(const pe of PlanEntries) {
    // pe[0] -> Title
    // pe[1] -> Data
    getRow(pe[0], pe[1]);
  }
}
```

Then with your entries with a simple for loops you can achieve your data appending everything into `<td>Data</td>` and return a `html` row;

```js
function getRow(index = "", data = null) {
  let years = getYears(); // Use your uniqueYears array here.
  let html = "<tr>"

  // Sort by year
  data = data.slice(0);
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.Year - b.Year;
  })

  html += `<td>${index}</td>`;

  for (const d of data) {
    while (years.length !== 0) {
      if (d.Year === years[0]) {
        html += `<td>${d.Value}</td>`;
        years.shift();
        break;
      } else {
        html += `<td>-</td>`;
      }
      years.shift();
    }
  }

  html += "</tr>";

    // console.log(html);
  return html;
}
```

The final result will be this html:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Participants</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>425</td>
</tr>
```

Or for your 2 year data participants:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Participants</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>389</td>
    <td>252</td>
</tr>
```

Now you only need to append in your html, as you want, take a look at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ow5rzv3/) if you need.

It is a little bit dirty code, but hope it helps!